# Problema con consulta a la base de datos en PHP, JSON nulo

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin, pdo

En este desarrollo del proyecto utilizo PHP para realizar consultas a la base de datos. Mi problema es que al momento de ejecutar la consulta el valor no recibo ninguna tabla y el JSON queda nulo, en la base de datos utilizo procedimientos almacenados y al ejecutarlos en PHPMyAdmin sí devuelve las tablas. Sin embargo ejecutarlo mediante PHP con el id correspondiente no devuelve nada, ni siquiera un arreglo vacío "[]" pero al momento de ingresar un id incorrecto la respuesta de la base de datos sí me devuelve un arreglo vacío. Anexo mi código PHP y mi consulta, de antemano muchas gracias:)

Código PHP:

```
    <?php
    include ('conexion.php');
    $idEmpresa = $_POST['idEmpresa'];

    $data = array();
    $consulta = 'CALL PA_ListaInteresados(?)';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($consulta);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $idEmpresa, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data['interesados'] = $rows;
    }

    echo $json = json_encode($data);
?>
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE idUsuario IN (SELECT idEmpleado 
                    FROM postulantes
                    WHERE idEmpresa = idRef);
```

Comment: En la tabla de la base de datos, ¿tienes palabras que están tildadas?

Comment: No, siempre me abstengo de escribir con símbolos a la hora de estar desarrollando código

Comment: Lo preguntaba porque puedes probar `json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: Acabo de intentarlo, pero sigo con el mismo error, ni siquiera recibo un arreglo vacío directamente la variable $json llega como null

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses el smbd y ejecutes el procedimiento almacenado a ver si se está ejecutando correctamente.  Ya que sí este tiene un error de SQL te devuelve null y no recibes los datos en memoria. Pero si pudiera ver el procedimiento te podría ayudar

Comment: Si se ejecuta con normalidad desde el smbd y me devuelve las tablas que me interesan, el problema se encuentra al momento de querer ejecutar el procedimiento por medio de PHP

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si creo que es lo que necesitas es hacer una procedimiento almacenado que haga una consulta a una tabla y la puedas leer, yo cree este procedimiento que hace unas consultas internas y las guardo en una tabla temporal por aquello de la consulta en memoria es mas rápida.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Crear_Tabla_balance_banca`(
    IN `fecha1` date,
    IN `fecha2` date,
    IN `transaccion` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `grupo` VARCHAR(3)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

set @f1 = fecha1;
set @f2 = fecha2;
set @transaccion = transaccion;
set @grupo = grupo;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS balance_banca (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `usuario` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        `fechpago` DATE NOT NULL,
        `fechtick` DATE NOT NULL,
        etc....
        `banco` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `fechpago`, `fechtick`),
        UNIQUE INDEX `unico` (`unico`)
    );

        SET @consulta = concat("INSERT INTO balance_banca (usuario,transaccion,sncheque,fecha,etc...)",
                               "SELECT * FROM balancebanca b INNER JOIN datbank d ON b.banco=d.id AND b.fechpago ",
                               "BETWEEN '",@f1,"' AND '",@f2,"' AND b.codgrupo='",@grupo,"' ",@transaccion," ORDER BY b.id ASC");

        PREPARE sentencia FROM @consulta;
      -- select @consulta; // En esta linea si la descomentas puedes ver la consulta al momento de ejecutarlo en el smbd
        EXECUTE sentencia;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE sentencia;
        SET @consulta = NULL;

END
```

y luego en mi pagina php hago la consulta en la tabla temporal creada que no la vas a ver en ningun lado si no llamas al procedimiento alamacenado

```
$sql = "CALL Crear_Tabla_balance_banca('".$fecha1."', '".$fecha2."', '".$detalle."', '".$optgrupo."')";
$r2 = Consulta($sql);
echo mysql_error(); // si hay un error solo para seguimiento
if($r2){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM balance_banca WHERE 1";
Consulta($sql);
while($data = FuncionExtraerDatos($r2)){
    informacion extraida en un arreglo $data['campo']
}
```

A esto se le llama sentencias preparadas en mysql